# Solr is highlighting wrong words

Tags: solr, solrj

I have a document which is

```
{'remaining': 'planet holly wood las vegas','id': 'c6d8e7e5-7ba9-4b68-ae0b-bb31ec4872f3'}
```

my query is `remaining:(((mirage OR *holly* OR (planet AND hollywood)) AND (las AND vegas)) AND id:c6d8e7e5-7ba9-4b68-ae0b-bb31ec4872f3)`

in the highlighting result:

```
{'c6d8e7e5-7ba9-4b68-ae0b-bb31ec4872f3': {'remaining': ['<em>planet</em> <em>holly</em> wood <em>las</em> <em>vegas</em>']}}
```

Why is `planet` being highlighted? I'm using solr 8.4
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's being highlighted because it's part of your query.

In general highlighting works across all the tokens being matched by the query, not just those giving a hit (and by default, a hit isn't even necessary in the field you're highlighting on - just that the token from the query is present in the highlighted value).

You can tweak this slightly by using `hl.requireFieldMatch`, but I'm not sure if that'll work with the optional clauses in your `OR` statement.

> **hl.requireFieldMatch**
>
> By default, false, all query terms will be highlighted for each field to be highlighted (hl.fl) no matter what fields the parsed query refer to. If set to true, only query terms aligning with the field being highlighted will in turn be highlighted.

The full list of [highlighting options is available in the reference guide](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_4/highlighting.html).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm pretty new to solr, is there a way to get matching terms in solr? In this example, I would like to get `holly`, `las` and `vegas`. Thanks~

Comment: Did you try `hl.requireFieldMatch`? What was the result?

Comment: I changed `hl.method` to `unified` and some additional parameters and it is highlighting the right words! Thank you!

Comment: It'd be helpful if you could add the exact parameters you used to your question or as a comment here for anyone that finds this question through a search engine in the future :-)